# default order and search for datatable boostrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I want to make my datatable bootstrap has the default in descending order and also you can see the search field to filter well as its pagination

But when I put the default order according to documentation the search field is hidden and the pagination

this is my code for order column but the search and pagination not visible

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example").dataTable({
     //uncoment for default order desc

    "sDom": "<'row'<'col-lg-11'i><'col-lg-1'>r>t<'row'<'col-lg-6'l><'col-lg-6'p>>",
        "order":[[3, 'desc']]

  });
});
```

When I commento this code , the pagination and search show

```
"sDom": "<'row'<'col-lg-11'i><'col-lg-1'>r>t<'row'<'col-lg-6'l><'col-lg-6'p>>",
            "order":[[3, 'desc']]
```

The example is here

http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple! Try this please! Work it. http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/68/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example").dataTable({ 
        "sDom": "<'row'<'col-lg-8'i><'col-lg-4'f>r>t<'row'<'col-lg-6'l><'col-lg-6'p>>",
            "order":[3, 'desc']
  });
});
```